# C# List<List<T>>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class with the following property: Education.cs
Apologize for the perhaps basic question

```
public List<List<Education>>data { get; set; }

public class Education
{
    public From school { get; set; }
    public From year { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

This is the class I have defined for deserializing  json string
From is  another .cs file

```
public string id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
```

Here is my json string

```
education": [
  {
     "school": {
        "id": "107751089258341",
        "name": "JNTU, Kakinada, India"
     },
     "year": {
        "id": "132393000129123",
        "name": "2001"
     },
     "type": "College"
  },
  {
     "school": {
        "id": "103710319677602",
        "name": "University of Houston"
     },
     "year": {
        "id": "113125125403208",
        "name": "2004"
     },
     "type": "Graduate School"
  }
```

]

Can someone tell me how to access the members of Education(school, year)? It could be a piece of cake for you.
In my aspx.cs, 
I have to write a foreach or any other to access my variables, school.name, year.name
Will have to work this access of class members into my aspx.cs

```
url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=education&access_token=" + oAuth.Token;
           json = oAuth.WebRequest(oAuthFacebook.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);
           List<Education>??? = js.Deserialize<List<??>(json)
```

Thanks
Smitha

Comment: Access them in what? A foreach loop?

Comment: doesn't look like complete code? Can you please complete it.

Comment: Is there a reason that you have a nested list?

Comment: And what type is `From` exactly??

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly are you trying to achieve? This seems a bit weird..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Slaks solution should work for you. Though I believe your data is better represented as `List<Education>` (or better still, `IEnumerable<Education>`) and what you may want to do is to Flatten it out.

It would be better to flatten it out at the source, to make sure your code is cleaner at other places.

If you are on .NET 3.5 you can do it like

```
var flattenData = data.SelectMany(x => x);
```

If you are on pre .NET 3.5 / C# 3.0, you can do it like this

```
//Your original code block
{
    IEnumerable<Education> flattenData = FlattenMyList(data);

    //use flatten data normally
}

IEnumerable<T> FlattenMyList<T> (List<List<T> data){
    foreach(List<T> innerList in data){
        foreach(T item in innerList){
            yield return item;
        }
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two `foreach` loops inside of eachother; one for each level of `List<>`.

Comment: @Smitha, see my answer. Again, @Slaks solution should work for you.